# PHP Get Generated Link From Another Page

Tags: php

I'm building checkout page which should, after purchase, show one-time download link.

```
www.mydomain/generate.php?mypassword
```

This link generate the one-time download link and it should show on the Checkout page.

At the moment I use:

```
$url = 'http://www.mydomain/generate.php?mypassword';
        $content = file_get_contents($url);
        $get_div = explode( '<div id="downloadlink" class="container">' , $content );
        $get_end_div = explode("</div>" , $get_div[1] );

        echo $get_end_div[0];
```

Any suggestions what would be better way to get the generated download link on the checkout page?

Whit the code above, I have one big problem. When client land on the checkoutpage s/he can refresh the page after file download when the page generate new link to her/him.

I'm here to learning so any suggestions/advises are welcome

Comment: Learn ajax and try ajax http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp and try

Comment: @Ima I wll, but I'm trying to get this done without AJAX

Comment: @Ima could you please make small example how this would be done by using AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion without ajax.

Generate password OR any data you want to display and either keep in session or in database and redirect to another page say http://www.mydomain/display.php. There you can show the password. also refresh will not generate new link.

Where is your "mypassword" is generated? "this doesn't prevent the file to generate new link" - What is generating new link? I thought mypassword is being generated again.

Assuming "http://www.mydomain/generate.php?mypassword" page is generating the password link, use following approach.

checkout.php

```
<?php
//After payment, you have mypassword now redirect to http://www.mydomain/generate.php';
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = 'mypassword';
header("Location:http://www.mydomain/display.php");
```

If generate.php is generating the the download link on load
display.php

```
$mypassword = !empty($_SESSION['mypassword']) ? $_SESSION['mypassword'] : null;
if (!empty($mypassword))
{
    $url = 'http://www.mydomain/generate.php?'.$mypassword;
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $get_div = explode( '<div id="downloadlink" class="container">' , $content );
    $get_end_div = explode("</div>" , $get_div[1] );
    echo $get_end_div[0];
    //Unset password to disable second download
    unset($_SESSION['mypassword']);
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid download link":
}
```

Comment: Make sense, but can't solve the logic behind it. Let's say I start session in the `generate.php` file (which, btw, generate the one-time download link) and I save the download link in the $_SESSION variable and then on the checkout page I include the `generate.php` file and use the $_SESSION variable on the checkout page after that. I can display the download link correctly but I missing something really important because this doesn't prevent the file to generate new link. So if you could give small example in order to help me to understand the logic behind this process I'd highly appreciateIt